# How to disable email verification? (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

How can i disable email verification in wordpress? What i want to do is The user isn't required to verify their email, but a verification mail will be sent to their inbox anyway. Is there any plugin to do so?

Comment: “*The user isn't required to verify their email, but a verification mail will be sent to their inbox anyway.*” May I ask why? Doesn’t this seem completely unnecessary? Why not just eliminate the email altogether...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly add this line of code to your site to disable “Email Verification” –

```
add_filter( 'wcfm_is_allow_email_verification', '__return_false' );
```

Check at WCfM Admin Setting -> Email From -> You may set email from name and email from address here.

And also see: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-disable-email-verification/

Comment: Thanks, But can you tell me where should i add this code ?

Comment: This code is only useful for Wordpress sites using the WCFM plugin, not for Wordpress sites in general